# How do I clean only those files from destDir that are no longer in my source dir using ant-javac

Tags: java, ant, build, javac

I have a requirement where I want to clean only those file in my destDir that are no longer present in sourceDir.
Ex: Assume I have a class: Student.java and College.java in my sourceDir. Running ant task for the first time would generated Student.class and College.class.
Now, if I delete Student.java from sourceDir and add another class 'Employee.java and run ant-javac task, I see a new file, 'Employee.class' generated in destDir, however the old file i.e 'Student.class' is still there even though 'Student.java' no longer exists in sourceDir.
My requirement is to delete all the files from destDir which are no longer in source dir.

PS: I already know that ant clean will work as it will clean my destDir before compiling, but due to few limitations wrt my application, I cannot clean the destDir before running javac

Answer (score 1):

Bit unusual like you point out, typical use case is to clean `destDir` directory berfore compiling... However you may do some specific clean by explicitly selecting resources that are no longer present in sources directory. You may use [Selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual-1.9.x/Types/selectors.html) to select which resources to delete. Following snippet should properly clean your `destDir` if run before  `javac` task :

```
<delete>
    <!-- select all classes that do not have a related source file -->
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="**/*.class">
        <not>
            <present targetdir="${src.dir}">
                <!-- use a regex mapper to handle inner classes -->
                <regexpmapper from="^([^\$]*)(\$.*)?.class" to="\1.java"/> 
            </present>
        </not>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```